# Error with push notifications from react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I was recently integrated into a project that is an application and I need to configure the entire development environment. So download Android Studio, Java 8, and Node.js. Configure environment variables, virtual devices for application execution. Once all this process is done, I start the mobile device emulator and within the Android Studio terminal I execute:

```
npm i
```

Thereafter:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

After executing some tasks, the application is installed inside the device and begins to load, but a few seconds later, it closes and this message appears:

** rnpushnotification.requestpermissions got 1 arguments, expected 0 **

This is part of the environment information I have:

```
  React Native Environment Info:
System:
  OS: Windows 10
  CPU: (8) x64 Intel (R) Core (TM) i7 CPU 860 @ 2.80GHz
  Memory: 16.60 GB / 23.99 GB
Binaries:
  npm: 6.14.8 - C: \ Program Files \ nodejs \ npm.CMD
IDEs:
  Android Studio: Version 4.1.0.0 AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069
```

The version of react-native that is inside the project is 0.59.10 and of react-native-push-notification is 3.3.0. I've been reviewing the issue for days and I haven't found the solution. the code where the PushNotification is used is the following:

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import { PushNotificationIOS, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { store } from './../Store'; 
import { REGISTER_DEVICE } from './../actions/types';
import ImageService from '../services/ImageService';


class NotificationService {

  static configure() {
    PushNotification.configure({

            // Register token logic
      onRegister: function(token) {
                 
                const device = {
                    tokenDispositivo: token.token,
                    plataforma: token.os,
                    imei: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
                };
                store.dispatch({
                    type: REGISTER_DEVICE,
                    payload: device
                });
            }, 
            
            // Logic process notification
      onNotification: function(notification) {
                // Notification
                const type = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.type : notification.type;        
                const alert = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.alert : notification.message;
                const title = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.title : notification.title; 
                switch (type) {
                    case 'another':
                        const url = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.fotoPerfil.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim() : notification.fotoPerfil.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim(); 
                        const user = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.usuario.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim() : notification.usuario.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim();
                        const loanId = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.idPrestamo.replace(' ','') : notification.idPrestamo.replace(' ','');
                        store.dispatch({
                            type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
                            modalProps: {
                                open: true,
                                title: title,
                                message: alert,
                                url: ImageService.getUrlFormat(url),
                                backdrop: false,
                                closeModal: () => {
                                    store.dispatch({
                                        type: 'HIDE_MODAL'
                                    });
                                    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
                                    Actions.summaryLoanAccepted({loanId});
                                }
                            },
                            modalType: 'approved'
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'another':
                        store.dispatch({
                            type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
                            modalProps: {
                                open: true,
                                backdrop: false,
                                message: alert,
                                title: title,
                                closeModal: () => {
                                    store.dispatch({
                                        type: 'HIDE_MODAL'
                                    });
                                    const loanId = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.idPrestamo.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim() : notification.idPrestamo.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim();
                                    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
                                    Actions.infoLoanOutstanding({ loanId: loanId });
                                }
                            },
                            modalType: 'billError'
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'another':
                        const urlComprobante = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.urlComprobante.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim() : notification.urlComprobante.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim();
                        store.dispatch({
                            type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
                            modalProps: {
                                open: true,
                                backdrop: false,
                                message: alert,
                                closeModal: () => {
                                    store.dispatch({
                                        type: 'HIDE_MODAL'
                                    });
                                    store.dispatch({
                                        type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
                                        modalProps: {
                                            open: true,
                                            imagesUrl: Platform.OS === 'ios' ?  [notification.data.urlComprobante.replace(' ','')]:[notification.urlComprobante.replace(' ','')],
                                            backdrop: false,
                                            closeModal: () => {
                                                Actions.reset('layoutApplicant');
                                                store.dispatch({
                                                    type: 'HIDE_MODAL'
                                                });
                                            },
                                        }, 
                                        modalType: 'image'
                                    });
                                    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
                                }
                            },
                            modalType: 'review'
                        });
                        break;

                        case 'another' :
                        store.dispatch({
                            type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
                            modalProps:{
                                open:true,
                                message: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.message : notification.message , 
                                closeModal:()=>{
                                    store.dispatch({
                                        type:'HIDE_MODAL'
                                    })
                                }
                            },
                            modalType: 'emptyState'
                        })
                        break;
                    default:
                        Actions.applicantHome(); 
                }
                const message = store.getState()
                notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);    
                PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(message.auth.messages);
            }, 
      // Android
      senderID: 'SenderId',

      // iOS
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },

      permissions: { alert: true, badge: true, sound: true },
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
        });
  }
};
export default NotificationService;
```

Comment: this problem is related to push notification, show the code of push notification

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: PushNotificationIOS is deprecated